# getting date in the format 31\05\2017 using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

i wanted to match all the dates matching 31\05\2017

i tried :

```
b=re.compile(r'31\05\2017')
b=re.compile('31\05\2017')
b=re.compile('31\\05\\2017')
b=re.compile(r'31\\05\\2017')
```

and what ever pattern i use , the below code gives same result

```
c=b.search('31\05\2017')
print(c.group())
```

gives '31\x05\x817'

how to get 31\05\2017

instead of null and other character being print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input to `b.search` actually consists of '31', a special character '\05', a special character '\201', and the digit '7'. You need to use a raw string literal for that too:

```
>>> re.compile(r'31\\05\\2017').match(r'31\05\2017')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='31\\05\\2017'>
```